# What is the right way to use TransactionScopes with MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I'm using one TransactionScope per request, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Login(string user, string pass)
{
    using (ServerContext context = new ServerContext ())
    {
        TransactionOptions transOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        transOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        transOptions.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOptions))
        {
           // Some logic and Linq queries here
        }
}
```

I perform some inserts, updates, deletes and proc calls inside the transaction scope
But, I got some rare DeadLock expceptions with high loads. So, i'm doing it right?
Or it's better to open a TransactionScope per operation? (But I need to rollback all operation if one of the set fails.)

Thnak you.

Comment: In general, this is correct. Are you really deadlocked in SQL Server, or do you mean blocking which causes the request to timeout?

Comment: You only need a TS when you have multiple `SaveChanges` calls that should be transactional. I assume that's what you do?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in L2S When you call SubmitChanges, LINQ to SQL checks to see whether the call is in the scope of a Transaction or if the Transaction property (IDbTransaction) is set to a user-started local transaction. If it finds neither transaction, LINQ to SQL starts a local transaction (IDbTransaction) and uses it to execute the generated SQL commands. When all SQL commands have been successfully completed, LINQ to SQL commits the local transaction and returns.

I have no ideas on MVC/EF but try wrapping like this :

```
 using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
 {
     using (ServerContext context = new ServerContext ())
     {


           // Some logic and Linq queries here
     }
     scope.Complete();
 }
```